# WebGL VBO and Integer Overflow depending on variable being attribute, uniform or a mix

Tags: glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

So I have this WebGL vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform vec3 pos0;
uniform float time;
attribute float t0;
attribute vec3 dir0;

void main() {
    float t = time - t0;
    gl_Position = camera * vec4(dir0, 1);
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

which works fine, but if I change just the following line

```
gl_Position = camera * vec4(pos0 + dir0 * t, 1);
```

Firefox complains:

```
Error: WebGL: drawElements: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 0!
```

And if I change the same line to the following:

```
gl_Position = camera * vec4(pos0, 1);
```

The error is different:

```
Error: WebGL: Drawing without vertex attrib 0 array enabled forces the browser to do expensive emulation work when running on desktop OpenGL platforms, for example on Mac. It is preferable to always draw with vertex attrib 0 array enabled, by using bindAttribLocation to bind some always-used attribute to location 0.
Error: WebGL: Integer overflow trying to construct a fake vertex attrib 0 array for a draw-operation with -1 vertices. Try reducing the number of vertices.
```

What is going on?

Edit: Chromium gives a clearer error message:

```
glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

Comment: How are you setting your uniforms and attributes? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about not posting any more code, I thought the cause was only in the shader, but it was not.

I am using `elm-webgl`, and the attributes are supposed to be set up. But the library does (did) not understand `float` attributes, so they weren't set.

So, if you ever get a similar error, check how you set your uniforms and attributes.